# Query to validate if a file already exists in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`where I am able to select some rows from it and insert it in another `DataGridView`, deleting the ones from the original `DataGridView`. To do that I will make some validations to see if there is an equal name file or something like that.

This is the code I am using in the transfer `Button` :

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dtrow2 in frm.dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
    con.Open();
    string querySelect = "SELECT FileName FROM SentRecycle WHERE FileName ='" + dtrow2.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "'";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(querySelect);

    frm.ShowDataGridView();
    cmd.Connection = con;

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read() == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This file already in use!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        if ((reader != null))
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

But I cannot delete it because when I put repeated file to test the application out it will always look for the first row and does not check the others. Do you have any idea how can I solve it?

Comment: I guess that's because of return statement, when you put repeated files, your first row filename matches in SentRecycle, then reader.Read() check it true, and you stopped function execution here, so next rows will not execute.

Comment: You are telling me that I should remove `if((reader != null)){ reader.Close();} return @SyedTalhaHai

Comment: I guess your code needs a little bit of change. you can close your reader whether or not your reader is null, and you should not use return statements, because when your first reader executes, return calls, foreach loop ends, means no next row is checked.

your code should be

    if (reader.Read() == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This file already in use!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    //Other stuff to do when file is in use
    }
    reader.Close();

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement will cause the `foreach` to stop after the first match.
Calling `return` will exit the method that it is in, regardless of any loops that may be executing, and that is the cause of your problem here.

Also, some others remarks:
 - The message does not say which file is in use.
 - For a dozen files in use, a dozen popups would show.
 - You do not need to create a new connection for every query, one is enough.
 - Using `SqlParameter` is better and safer than concatenating the filename into the query.

The result would look something like this:

```
public bool AreFilesInUse()
{
    var FilesInUse = new List<string>();
    con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
    con.Open();
    var sql = "SELECT FileName FROM SentRecycle WHERE FileName = @file";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@file", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    cmd.Connection = con;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow dtrow2 in frm.dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        var file = dtrow2.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@file"].Value = file;

        // frm.ShowDataGridView(); // does not seem useful here, maybe before the loop

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
            FilesInUse.Add(file);  // remember file name

        reader.Close();
    }

    bool foundAny = FilesInUse.Count > 0;
    if (foundAny)
    {
        var files = string.Join("\r\n", FilesInUse);
        MessageBox.Show("The following files are already in use:\r\n" + files, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    con.Close();
    return foundAny;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

that is because you dont let your code to check all rows in your `foreach` loop. remove `return` keyword and check other ones. if you need these file names in somewhere else, put them in a list or something like that. also check if file name is null or empty to handle exceptions. check this:

```
 var fileNamelist = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow dtrow2 in frm.dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
    con.Open();
    //if null or empty set it to a default value. here i set it to "".
    var fileName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtrow2.Cells[2].Value.ToString())
                               ? ""
                               : dtrow2.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    string querySelect = "SELECT FileName FROM SentRecycle WHERE FileName ='" + fileName  + "'";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(querySelect);

    frm.ShowDataGridView();
    cmd.Connection = con;

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read() == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This file already in use!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        fileNamelist.add(fileName);
        if ((reader != null))
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
        //return; this will finish loop. so removed!
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. Does not work, because it will always search in the first row of the second `DataGridView`

Comment: @LeugimSnitram aha! what is frm.ShowDataGridView()? that may stop your loop.

Comment: I commented it and then run the app and tested your code. It will show the "This file already in use" but will delete anyway

Comment: I've run the code and it will always search for the first cell of the second datagridview

Comment: @LeugimSnitram is it after uncomment  frm.ShowDataGridView() line?

Comment: I think that this is not working because of the select query. This is always looking from the first row